# Flux of Curl with given function

Tags: vector-fields, solid-geometry, stokes-theorem, circulant-matrices, divergence-theorem

Let $F$ from $R^3$ to $R$ defined by $F(x, y, z) = (x − yz, xz, y)$.
Let $S$ be the surface obtained by rotating the graph of $x=2^z+3^z$ with $z ∈ [0, 1]$, around
the $z$-axis (with normal vectors oriented outward). Calculate the flux of $∇×F$ across
S.

I know how to compute the flux of vector field: either by Stokes Theorem, or directly. But, I have no idea how on this problem it should be dealt with. Any suggestions would be strongly welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

Since it is always true that $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \times F)=0$, Gauss' Law tells us that the total flux of a curl through any closed surface always vanishes.

A closed surface is formed from ...

the curved surface you wish to calculate the flux through, call this $S_1$,

and a disk of radius $2$ parallel to the $xy$ plane  at $z=0$ call this $S_2$ ,

and finally a disk of radius $5$ parallel to the $xy$ plane  at $z=1$ call this $S_3$

This closed surface is congruent to the boundary of the volume of revolution formed by the graph of $y=2^x + 3^x$ revolved about the x-axis between $x=0$ and $x=1$ ...

[image]

the fluxes through the three surfaces are related by ...

$$\phi_1+\phi_2+\phi_3=0$$
we can calculate $\phi_2$ and $\phi_3$ directly using the fact that the $z$ component of $\nabla \times F$ is just $-2z$

so $\phi_2=0$ and $\phi_3 = -2(25 \pi)$

so $\phi_1 = 50 \pi$

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you found that rotating the graph of $x=2^z+3^z$ around $z$-axis (given boundary conditions) leads to disk of radius 2 and 5? I have trouble on understating what this rotation means?

Comment: I have edited my answer to be more complete in that respect